# Prevent default behavior of submit in Ajax.BeginForm with .on() method of jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-events

I have a form in my view where I use `Ajax.BeginForm`. I want to change the default behavior of the submit button with Javascript code. I've attached a handler with `.on()` method and inside the handler, I called the `preventDefault()` method. I'm wondering to know why when I attach the handler to the root DOM element, the default behavior is not cancelled but when I attach the handler directly to the form DOM element, the default behavior is cancelled.

**The view:**

```
@using (this.Ajax.BeginForm("GetList", "Report", null, new AjaxOptions(), new {id = "OptionForm"}))
{
   <input type="submit" id="submitButton"/>
}
```

**The script to attach handler to the root DOM element (Doesn't work):**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(function () {         
      $(document).on("submit", "#OptionForm", refreshGrid);
   })
</script>
```

**The handler:**

```
refreshGrid: function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "POST",
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.success) {
                $("#ReferenceList").html(data.result);
            }
            else {
                $("#ValidationSummary").html(data.result);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

**And finally the code to attach the handler to the form DOM element (Works):**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(function () {         
      $("#OptionForm").submit = refreshGrid;
   })
</script>
```

Comment: @Darin, you're right but even if I use the tag <form>, I just want to know why the default behavior is cancelled with a handler attached directly to the form DOM element.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's really no point of using an `Ajax.BeginForm` if you are going to handle the AJAX submission manually. A standard `Html.BeginForm` would suffice, because you don't need to cumulate multiple `.submit()` handlers:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("GetList", "Report", null, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "OptionForm" }))
{
   <input type="submit" id="submitButton" />
}
```

and then:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(function () {         
      $(document).on('submit', '#OptionForm', refreshGrid);
   });
</script>
```

and the `refreshGrid` function:

```
var refreshGrid = function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: this.action,
        type: this.method,
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.success) {
                $('#ReferenceList').html(data.result);
            }
            else {
                $('#ValidationSummary').html(data.result);
            }
        }
    });

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Hi @Darin, your solution looks much more sexy. I will used it. The fact that I can use 'this.method' and 'this.action' is wonderful instead of the ugly hardcorded string 'POST'. But and but :), do you know why Ajax.BeginForm must be hooked to the form DOM Element? Is Asp.Net MVC that control the hook of the handler to the DOM element or is the browser? Is this why I must hook to the element directly?

Comment: You return false at the end of the function but I read in a lot of places that it's a bad practice because if the $.ajax method failed, the return statement will never be called and the default behavior will not be cancelled. What do you think about that?